# What influences NHibernate to use outer joins instead of inner joins?

Tags: nhibernate, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have several one-to-many mappings in an NHibernate project that are configured to use `Sets`.

Without doing projects, and with `max_fetch_depth` set to 2, NHibernate appears to always use outer joins instead of inner joins.

Is there a reason for this? The mapping structure is the equivalent of:

```
Category
  +- Document.Category
    +- Document.User
```

Just a plain one-to-many setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if Nhibernate did inner joins, that means that Categorys that have no Documents would not be fetched.
This is why nHibernate always uses outer joins unless you specifically query otherwise.

Comment: Makes sense, although this presumably means NHibernate brings back far more rows than it needs unless you write all the collection queries yourself?

Comment: no.. why would you say that? don't you need rows of `Category` that don't contain any `Document`s?

Comment: @sJohnny I can see why it does it now, as it suits most scenarios. For many-to-manys though, this does create a huge recordset. But I guess you're meant to approach these with custom criteria queries